# How do I copy a directory structure from one Windows server to another and retain the ACL information?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I need to decommission a file server which is the target of a folder redirection GPO.

I used the instructions in Mark Minasi's Server2003 book to setup the original share.

I would like to copy the whole folder to a new server and know that I did it right from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`robocopy /mirror C:\ \\ServerB\C$\TmpFolder`

[Robocopy is part of the Serveer 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

Comment: XCOPY will copy ACLs, too. Use the "/X" switch and you'll get the DACLs, ownership information, and SACLs.